# Fibonacci using DCG

Tags: prolog, fibonacci, dcg

I am in the process of trying to create the fibonacci series using DCG in prolog. I have this for starters, however I have no idea why the code is not being carried out.

Here is the code below:

```
fib --> [0], [1].
fib --> [X, Y], {Z is X + Y}, [Z].
```

I get an error that the variables are not sufficiently instantiated. I know that this solution is far from the final one, however I am just struggling to comprehend why this is not possible. Any advice and input would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Use e.g. `trace` to see what's happening - https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=debugger

Answer (score 3):

Not efficient, but short:

```
% Seed with initial 2 values
fib(1, 0) --> [0, 1].
% Get previous 2 values, then sum them
fib(S, P1) --> fib(P1, P2), { S is P1 + P2 }, [S].
```

Results in swi-prolog:

```
?- phrase(fib(F, _), L).
F = 1,
L = [0, 1] ;
F = 1,
L = [0, 1, 1] ;
F = 2,
L = [0, 1, 1, 2] ;
F = 3,
L = [0, 1, 1, 2, 3] ;
F = 5,
L = [0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5] ;
F = 8,
L = [0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8] ;
F = 13,
L = [0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13]
...
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the feedback. This is super helpful! Out of interest's sake, it there a way to do it where the you are not calling arguements for the DCG. For example, it is defined as fib --> [0, 1].

Comment: I don't believe so - the 2 integers to be summed need to be available/referenced *somehow*.

Answer (score 3):

I agree with @brebs that doing it without args to the DCG is difficult; if the `[0,1]` is consumed from the list by the first call, the next call with no arguments and no inputs has nothing to add, and breaks.

The closest I can get is with pushback notation:

```
nextFib, [B,C] --> [A,B], { C is A+B }.

fib --> nextFib, ([] | fib).
```

which behaves as:

```
?- phrase(fib, [0,1|Fs], Rest).
Rest = [1, 1|Fs] ;
Rest = [1, 2|Fs] ;
Rest = [2, 3|Fs] ;
Rest = [3, 5|Fs] ;
Rest = [5, 8|Fs] ;
Rest = [8, 13|Fs] ;
Rest = [13, 21|Fs] ;
Rest = [21, 34|Fs] ;
...
```

Which is not a correct output, it is consuming the first two numbers `[A,B]` and dropping them, pushing `[B,C]` back onto the front of the list, and we're looking at them un-consumed. But is going through the Fibonacci sequence in some way.

---

To gather them up instead of dropping them, we're back to needing an argument:

```
nextFib(A), [B,C] --> [A,B], { C is A+B }.

fib([F|Fs]) --> nextFib(F), ([] | fib(Fs)).
```

Then:

```
?- phrase(fib(Fibs), [0,1|Fs], _).
Fibs = [0|_1682] ;
Fibs = [0, 1|_1360] ;
Fibs = [0, 1, 1|_1366] ;
Fibs = [0, 1, 1, 2|_1372] ;
Fibs = [0, 1, 1, 2, 3|_1378] ;
Fibs = [0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5|_1384] ;
Fibs = [0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8|_1390] ;
Fibs = [0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13|_1396] ;
Fibs = [0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21|_1402] ;
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I appreciate the help!